# Return multiple arrays through functions (processing)

Tags: java, arrays

So i need to return multiple arrays from a function in process. The problem is i don't know which function value to use? (eg int function, string function etc) Also, how do i return multiple values? I need the send barrierx and barriery from arrayGen() to barriers(). Thanks for your help!

Final:

```
int barriers(){
    if (R == 1){     
        while (size>0){
            barrierx[size-1] = randomInt(512);
            barriery[size-1] = randomInt(512);    
            size = size - 1;
        }

       while (sizeC>0){
           ellipse( barrierx[sizeC-1],  barriery[sizeC-1], 100, 100);
           sizeC = sizeC - 1;        
       }
       sizeC = sizeB;     
       R = 0;
    }
    return 5;
   }

  int arrayGen(){
      int size = randomInt(11);
      int sizeB = size;
      int sizeC = size;

      int[] barrierx = new int[size];
      int[] barriery = new int[size];
  }
```

EDIT:

```
int arrayGen(){

  int size = randomInt(11);
  int sizeB = size;
  int sizeC = size;
  int[] result = new int[2];

  int[] barrierx = new int[size];
  int[] barriery = new int[size];

   while (size>0){
    barrierx[size-1] = randomInt(512);
    barriery[size-1] = randomInt(512);    
    size = size - 1;
  }


  result[0] = barrierx;
  result[1] = barriery;
return result;
}
```

type mismatch cannot convert from int[] to int

Comment: if you want to return multiple arrays, return an `int[][]` ( array of arrays )

Comment: You could use return a `List`

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.  When asking a question, try to be as specific as possible, as well as show what kind of answers/attempts you already made. If we have to guess any information, is likely that the help wont be helpfull.... Welcome to stackoverflow, and good luck onwards.

Comment: @KevinEsche How would that work? I tried return: int[barrierx][barriery]; but it said error on class?

Answer (score 1):

Define a class containing all the data fields you need. Then return an object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return multiple values from a function, but you can return a single value that wraps them all.

If the values types are homogeneous, use an array or a Collection of that type, as suggested in the comments by Kevin Esche. For example :

```
int[] barrierx = new int[size];
int[] barriery = new int[size];
return {barrierx, barriery};  // later access barrierx by result[0] and barriery by result[1]
```

or more explicitely :

```
int[] barrierx = new int[size];
int[] barriery = new int[size];
int[][] result = new int[size][2];
result[0] = barrierx;
result[1] = barriery;
return result;
```

As you can see from the type declaration of the returned value, the method signature needs to be `int[][]`.

If the values types are heterogeneous, use a class whose fields contain these values, with the specific types needed, as answered by JF Meier.

Comment: Both arrays are full of randomly generating integers. How would i do this?

Comment: Does my example makes it clear? Note that the content of the arrays does not matter (altough their size does, since it's part of their "type").

Comment: Yes it makes sense to me, but i am getting 'type mismatch cannot convert from int[] to int' on result, barrierx and barriery, see my edit? Thanks. I am using processing if that helps.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, I've answered this problem in a comment on your question : you need to change your method signature since it does not return a single into but rather an array of arrays of ints

Comment: Sweet this works great! I also need to return an integer (size) in the same function along with the two arrays. Is this possible?

Comment: either that or i need to get the length of the array, in the new function where i am sending the arrays, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes you can, use `arr.length`. You might want to check out the [Oracle tutorial on arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Also if it hadn't been possible, you could always have reffered to the last part of my answer (or to JF Meier's answer) and returned an object containing the two arrays and their size.

Comment: Everything works now except i am getting arrayoutofbound exception(0) and (1) on the result[0] = boundary lines

Comment: I'm sorry but it looks like it'll never end if I continue answering you : the answer to your problem is in my answer, and I've already commented on it. I've already devoted much more effort to your problem than is worth 0 reputation points. I highly recommend your read the tutorial I linked (and check out a tutorial on data types if it's too hard a read) because it looks like you have difficulties conceptualizing the data you want to handle.